# RSync - Permission denied (13) while executing rsync as a root

Tags: permissions, rsync

I am trying to set up hourly rsync beetwen my local machine and remote server. I have already created a ssh certificate to enable login less connection to remote machine.

Now however when I execute the following command from my root account:

```
rsync -avzhep /home/  vps:/
```

I got the following error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec /home/: Permission denied (13)
```

This seems strange to me as I am root and i can normally access /home/ directory.

Could you please advice what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-e` option is used to run a different remote shell, actually you are trying to execute "/home/" which is not permitted.  Try :

```
rsync -avzh /home/  vps:/
```

By the way :

The "/" at the end of `/home/` indicates that you want to copy the content of `/home` to the remote root directory ("vps:/"). 
If your target is the remote "/home" directory, you should use :

```
rsync -avzh /home/  vps:/home
```

or

```
rsync -avzh /home  vps:/
```

Comment: How Can I `rsync` with port specific remote ?

Comment: Port is only working when `-e` is present , Please get me a clean solution