# Rsync can't find file or directory on receiver, possibly because of permission issues resulting from specifying ssh, required for indicating port

Tags: ssh, permissions, rsync

I'd like to rsync some files to a remote server.

I tried

`rsync -rav --delete -e 'ssh -p "$SSH_PORT" "$SSH_USERNAME"@"$SSH_HOST"' ./ /home/"$SSH_USERNAME"/src/`

I receive the error

`rsync: [Receiver] mkdir "/home/SSH_USERNAME/src" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

I'm using the `-e 'ssh -p` format because that seems to be the [recommended way to specify non-standard ssh port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549945/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-different-ssh-port-when-using-rsync) for a given server.

However, I'm concerned [based on other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232043/163373) that this might be causing permission weirdness preventing rsync from writing.

On the remote server, the given location does indeed exist, apparently with proper permissions:

*on remote server*

```
SSH_USERNAME@SSH_HOST:~$ pwd
/home/SSH_USERNAME
SSH_USERNAME@SSH_HOST:~$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 6 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 4096 Jun 14 03:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root       root       4096 Jun 13 23:18 ..
-rw------- 1 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME  221 Jun 14 03:44 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME  220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 3771 Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 4096 Jun 14 00:44 .cache
drwx------ 3 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 4096 Jun 14 00:44 .gnupg
-rw-r--r-- 1 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME  807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
drwxrwxr-x 3 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 4096 Jun 14 19:53 src
drwx------ 2 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 4096 Jun 14 00:52 .ssh
SSH_USERNAME@SSH_HOST:~$ cd ..
SSH_USERNAME@SSH_HOST:~$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root       4096 Jun 13 23:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root       root       4096 Jun 13 22:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 caleb      caleb      4096 Jun 14 01:15 caleb
drwxr-xr-x  6 SSH_USERNAME SSH_USERNAME 4096 Jun 14 03:44 SSH_USERNAME
```

**How can I rsync a directory to a server with a non-standard SSH port?**

Just in case:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 1):

Even absent any other changes, your `rsync` syntax is a tad off.  I'd suggest changing to:

```
rsync -rav --delete -e 'ssh -p "$SSH_PORT"' ./ "$SSH_USERNAME"@"$SSH_HOST":/home/"$SSH_USERNAME"/src/
```

Also, read `man 5 ssh_config` regarding how to construct SSH "aliases" that tie a particular host address, username, port (and possibly other parameters like an SSH identity key) to a convenient nickname.  Then whenever you SSH to that nickname, `ssh` will use those particular parameters for the connection.

In your `~/.ssh/config`, add:

```
Host Nickname
  Hostname $SSH_HOST
  Port $SSH_PORT
  User $SSH_USERNAME
```

where:

```
Nickname is a convenient name of your choice
$SSH_HOST is the proper name, or perhaps an IP
$SSH_PORT is the port number
$SSH_USERNAME is the desired username
```

For example:

```
Host foobar
  Hostname foobar.example.com
  Port 2222
  User myusername
```

Then your `rsync` syntax becomes:

```
rsync -rav --delete ./ foobar:/home/"$SSH_USERNAME"/src/
```

If the home directory of user `$SSH_USERNAME` on host `foobar` is already `/home/$SSH_USERNAME`, then you can likely shorten the remote path of the `rsync` command:

```
rsync -rav --delete ./ foobar:src/
```

Comment: This is helpful, and if I need to go down this path using `sed` or something I will, so thank you for this. I forgot to mention I'm aware you can set port etc in ssh config, but this rsync command is meant to eventually run on a github action (like a deploy hook basically) which runs in a little vm thing they spin up, so I'd prefer something "inline" if possible. It's probably not a huge deal to modify the ssh config as part of the build process on every go though.